# Is it possible to have a custom function to encapsulate $t function?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-component, node-modules, vue-i18n

I am currently using Vue-i18n.

Is it possible to call the `$t` function in another `Vue.prototype` function?

What I would like to do is to have a custom function `$ba_t` which will encapsulate `$t` function in it.

Is it possible to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: What you need custom function `$ba_t` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a plugin:

```js
const myPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$ba_t = function(param) {
      return this.$t(param);
    };
  },
};
Vue.use(myPlugin);
```

This plugin create a new method that call the old method.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)